# Freemarker parameter doesn't know what it is

Tags: freemarker

I have a source from the reportTest area. I don't know if I'm allowed to show it but it kinda looks like this:

```
 (reportTests.test_thing.view_moreThings["adjustedIssuePrice"])
```

now this parameter IS a number! but for some reason it doesn't know that.
I tried "?eval" , "?number"...nothing. I can to basic mathematics on the parameter but I not when I call it (and I need to call it)
did anyone encounter something like this before?

[image]

this is what i get

Answer (score 1):

That thing isn't a number, but a `String`, as the error message says. Just because a string looks like a number for a human, it's not a number as far as most computer languages are concerned. The recommended solution is to improve that data-model so that it uses a number (like an `Integer` or `BigDecimal`, typically) instead of `String` there. If that's not feasible, then `?number` should work (like `${foo.bar * bundle.UNITS_CALC_NEW_TOTC?number}`).  What error message do you get with it?

Comment: If you show the concrete example and the error message with `?number`, then it might turns out what the problem is.

Comment: your right! i changed the data-model and now it works. thanks